# Python3.6 Ldap3 modify_dn ( Renaming + Moving User to another OU)

Tags: python-3.x, ldap3

I'm trying to rename AD user Test_2 to testing using python LDAP3 as well as moving user to another OU too.

***NOTE: instead of domain name i am using IP and rest is same.***

i am successfully able to fetching user details using the same manner (Mentioned in NOTE), but during renaming and moving user one OU to other OU, i am getting negative result; the funny thing is code doesn't showing any error it is showing only FALSE result.

```
import ldap3
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL

server=Server(host='IP',port=389,get_info=ALL) 
conn=Connection(server,user='adtest\admin',password='admin@123') conn.bind()
print (conn.modify_dn('cn=Test_2,OU=Test,OU=adtest','cn=Testing'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check conn.result to get the reason of the failure.